# How can I extract unit preceded by number with str_extract?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I think str_extract can do this, but I fail to figure out this. my data contains chinese character so there is no blank white between characters. I simulate the data in english as:

```
> dd<-c("wwe12hours,fgg23days","ffgg12334hours,23days","ffff1days")
> target <- c("hours","days","hours","days")
> target
[1] "hours" "days"  "hours" "days"
```

How can I achieve the *target*? 
my real case is:

```
> dd <- c("腹痛发热12小时,再发2天","腹痛132324月，再发1天","发热4天")
> target <- c("小时","月","天")
> target
[1] "小时" "月"   "天"
```

Comment: Do you know in advance which units are likely to appear? Or do the data contain all kinds of different units, and you're not sure which ones might appear?

Comment: I cannot know in advance the name of units; for example, month can be written in "M","Mon","Month" or "months"; many hand-writing variants. But I can know the unit is preceded by a number; and I only need the first one.

Comment: base regex: `sub("\\d+", "", unlist(regmatches(dd, gregexpr("\\d\\w+", dd))))`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for regex to capture the units. Since you have a vector of length three, we would prefer to return another vector of length three. From your example(ENGLISH ONE) it is not clear how you obtain a target of 4 units. Although I perceive you meant to have 5 if not 3.

here is how you could tackle. This can generally be used for any language:

English:

```
gsub("\\p{L}*+\\d+", "", dd, perl = TRUE)
[1] "hours,days" "hours,days" "days"
```

Chinese:

```
gsub("\\p{L}*+\\d+", "", dd, perl = TRUE)
[1] "小时,天" "月,天"   "天"     

regmatches(ddc,gregexpr("(?<=\\d)\\p{L}+",ddc,perl = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "小时" "天"  

[[2]]
[1] "月" "天"

[[3]]
[1] "天"
```

or if you want to use other packages:

using `str_extract_all`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(ddc,"(?<=\\d)\\p{L}+")
```

Comment: What's the exact meaning of `\\p{L}`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann `\p{L}` is to match any single character that belongs to the letter category. I do not know chinese, so had to think of those as letters as they are letters in english. Probably they are not. But I used the english to solve the chinese

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_match_all` :

```
library(stringr)
unlist(sapply(str_match_all(dd, '\\d+(\\w+)'), function(x) x[, 2]))
#[1] "hours" "days"  "hours" "days"  "days"
```

This captures the first word that comes after a number.

where

```
str_match_all(dd, '\\d+(\\w+)') #returns
#[[1]]
#     [,1]      [,2]   
#[1,] "12hours" "hours"
#[2,] "23days"  "days" 

#[[2]]
#     [,1]         [,2]   
#[1,] "12334hours" "hours"
#[2,] "23days"     "days" 

#[[3]]
#     [,1]    [,2]  
#[1,] "1days" "days"
```

---

As mentioned by @Onyambu, we can use a lookbehind regex to avoid using `sapply` to subset the capture group.

```
unlist(str_extract_all(dd,"(?<=\\d)[A-z]+"))
```

Comment: instead of `sapply`, don't you think using a look-behind would be faster? eg`unlist(str_match_all(dd,"(?<=\\d)[A-z]+"))`

Comment: Yes, thanks, initially I was trying something similar. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
cleaned_dd <- gsub("[[:punct:]].*", "",
                   unlist(lapply(strsplit(
                     gsub("[[:digit:]]", " ", dd), "\\s+"
                   ), '[',-1)))
```

Comment: you know `gsub` is vectorized hence no need for lapply. You could just do `strsplit(gsub("\\w+\\d+","",dd),",")` or  `unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\w+\\d+","",dd),","))`

Comment: The lapply is dropping the first element in each element of the list.

Comment: but what is the purpose of using it while gsub does everything? Lapply You should learn regex in order to solve this kind of issues. You are replacing the digits with space just to split on the space. Why not just split on the digits? eg `strsplit(dd,'\\d+')`??